# Wi-fi chipset with SDIO interface in SPI bus mode

Tags: spi, embedded, wifi, sdio

I want to connect a Wifi-chipset, which offers an SDIO interfaces to a microcontroller that only supports SPI.

As far as I understand from the specifications, every SD card can be connected to a host microcontroller on its respective SPI ports and then be operated in SPI bus mode. Now there are also certain Wifi-chipsets that have an SDIO interface for the connection to the host microcontroller. Maybe my question is trivial, but do also all Wifi-chipsets that offer an SDIO interface support the SPI bus mode? Or does it have to be explicitely supported by the manufacturer? Does the supported SDIO version have an influence?
Because in the datasheet of the Wifi-Chipset it does not mention the SPI transfer mode.

Edit: I am not looking for a suggestion which specific chipset to use. I know there are wi-fi chipsets that support spi or spi transfer mode.

Comment: DO you have part numbers for these Wifi chipsets?

Comment: Check the SDIO spec itself...

Comment: The SDIO spec talks about "card mandatory support" for the spi transfer mode, which lets me believe that all sd cards have to support it. On the other hand I didn't read any mention to other devices using sdio. This fact combined with Wi-Fi chipset datasheets, which do not mention spi transfer mode have me wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I came accross the answer in an extension part of the SDIO specifications.
In section **1.1.2** of ***Part E1 Simplified - SDIO Simplified Specification V3.00*** embedded SDIO Devices such as Wifi chips with SDIO interface are mentioned.

There it says that the SPI mode is **optional** for embedded SDIO devices.